# For geom_violin, how is the total area of all violins specified?

Tags: r, ggplot2, violin-plot

In a call to `geom_violin` within `ggplot2`, you can specify that the area of each violin should be proportional to the number of observations making up that violin by specifying `scale="count"`.

I assume this operates internally by taking some total amount of area (let's call this amount X) and dividing it proportionally among all violins to be plotted. This is what I want, except that this can result in pretty narrow violins if there is substantial enough disparity in N between groups such that some groups have relatively low N. In my case, this just makes the fill color kind of hard to see.

I think this can be largely solved, in my case at least, by simply expanding X a little bit so that the really small violins get just enough area to still be readable. In other words, **I want to retain variation in area between violins according to the number of observations but increase the "pool" of total area being divided amongst violins**, so that every one gets slightly bigger.

Anyone have any idea how one might accomplish this? There's gotta be a toggle for this. I've tried fussing with arguments to `geom_violin` such as `width`, `size`, `violinwidth`, and such, but no luck so far...

EDIT: Code for a boring but reproducible "sample" data set that one can experiment with.

```
y = runif(100, 1, 10)
x = as.factor(rep(c(1,2), times=50))
z = as.factor(c(rep(1, 10), rep(2, 90)))
df=data.frame(x, y, z)
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=z)) + geom_violin(scale="count")
```

Comment: Please provide a small reproducible example to facilitate testing of potential solutions.

Comment: Added something boring but hopefully exemplary enough to be useful.

Comment: @Bajcz Have you found any solution yet?

Comment: @MarkSeygan No, I haven't, but maybe I will try to poke around in the geom_violin code this week and see what I can figure out.

Comment: I found I can do it through `width` in the `geom_violin`'s parethesis.

Comment: Can you expand on this? `width` is marked as a computed variable in the help; others on this list, like `count` and `violinwidth` are ignored when I include them in the `geom_violin` call. So, I'm not sure why `width` is not being ignored, since it is not a function argument. Also, it's not clear to me what `width` is doing...for me, values above ~ 1.5 not only change the shape of my violins, but also their position and orientation on the graph. Any ideas what's going on there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adjusting `width` parameter inside `geom_violin`. But make sure to also use `position_dodge` to avoid overlapping plots.

Using your data

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=z)) + geom_violin(scale="count", width=2)
```

will give the following plot
[image]

allowing some gap between the plots by using `position_dodge`

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=z)) + geom_violin(scale="count", width=2, position=position_dodge(width=0.5))
```

This will give you the following non-overlapping plot 
[image]

Comment: Great answer, thanks! Can you explain, if you can, why `width` is a computed variable that the model accepts as an argument when other such variables like `count` and `violinwidth` are ignored? I think that's why I was assuming `width` couldn't be the right thing to be manipulating...